# Exporting executable jar changes directory of images

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a problem exporting my Eclipse project to an executable jar. I think I do it right but the jar launches than aborts. So I tried with "java -jar nameofproject.jar" and it 
says :

```
Unable to load image :/images/dialogs/server-database.png
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)....
```

So I decompressed the jar and looked at the directory structure within it and I was surprised to see that my "images" package was included in an unwanted "src" directory, making it impossible for the jvm to find them.

So here is the original project structure in Eclipse:

[image]

and here is the directory structure in the unpacked jar :

[image]

(the images directory is under the "src" directory which prevents the jvm from finding the pics)

Any idea about how to solve that ?